# Change value of all elements in a sum list via class/function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

We  are writing a program in python3, where we want to add values to three lists by using a class:

```
trusted_reference, trusted_initialize, trusted_sum_list = ([] for i in range(3))

class trust():

    def __init__(self, bool, sum):
        self.bool = bool
        self.sum = sum

    def initialize(self):
        trusted_initialize.append(self.bool)
        trusted_sum_list.append(self.sum) #ELEMENTS CAN CHANGE

    def reference(self):
        trusted_reference.append(self.bool)
        trusted_sum_list.append(self.sum) #ELEMENTS CAN CHANGE
```

First, we add values by saying following:

```
for i in range(3)
    trusted_sum_new = trusted_sum + 0.1
    initialize = trust(1, trusted_sum_new)
    initialize.initialize()
```

When calling above lines of codes, our lists looks like this:

```
trusted_initialize = {1, 1, 1}
trusted_reference = {}
trusted_sum_list = {0.1, 0.1, 0.1}
```

Then we run following lines of code, AFTER THE INITIALIZE:

```
for i in range(3)
    trusted_sum_new = trusted_sum + 0.1
    reference = trust(1, trusted_sum_new)
    reference.reference()
```

and we then want to see something like this:

```
trusted_initialize = {1, 1, 1}
trusted_reference = {1, 1, 1}
trusted_sum_list = {0.2, 0.2, 0.2}
```

and NOT:

```
trusted_initialize = {1, 1, 1}
trusted_reference = {1, 1, 1}
trusted_sum_list = {0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1}
```

Comment: Can you please remove superfluous details from your question? It is really hard to tell what you want, and what problem you encounter. What's the purpose of the ``trust`` class? It doesn't do anything other than provide the arguments to ``reference`` and ``initialize``, which could just as well be functions that take the arguments directly. Why do you expect the lists to be of length three in the second case? The previous content is never removed.

Comment: Take note that your desired output uses set notation, not list notation. ``{1, 1, 1}`` is ``{1}``.

Comment: Thanks for your response, MisterMiyagi. I forgot to mention that length of the lists will always be equal to each other. And as example i just picked 3 elements. Can you specify what you mean by superfluous? I have not added anything in my question which I didn't find necessary to share, for you to be able to help me

Comment: Keep in mind that I don't have years of experience, and that I am fairly new to python. Hence my lack of finding the best solution to my issue and therefore asking this question

Comment: Maybe what I have done is the wrong way of achieving what I want? Constructive criticism is just as valuable as a solution.

Comment: As said before, why do you have a class? It does not serve any purpose, and could be replaced by two functions ``initialize(bool, sum)`` and ``reference(bool, sum)``. Why do you expect ``trusted_sum_list`` to be of length 3 at the end, even though you append 6 times? Why do you expect its elements to be ``0.2``, even though you only append ``trusted_sum + 0.1`` (where ``trusted_sum = 0``) in both the first and second case?

Comment: @Buster3650 python has very limited facilities for in-place manipulation of list elements (beyond set/push/pop). You want to either clear() then update the lists (possibly having copied their contents elsewhere) or create new modified-lists from the old one and replace the old list with those. The latter is probably more normal. Alternatively, store some sort of mutable object (instead of integers), then you can modify those in-place easily.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
for i in range(3)
    trusted_sum_new = trusted_sum + 0.1
    initialize = trust(1, trusted_sum_new)
    initialize.initialize()
```

you create 3 objects of 'trust' but you don't keep the references to the objects.

With

```
for i in range(3)
    trusted_sum_new = trusted_sum + 0.1
    reference = trust(1, trusted_sum_new)
    reference.reference()
```

you create 3 new objects of 'trust' and you call reference() for each object. This only calls append to the arrays. The objects don't know anything about previous values in the arrays.

I think what would be better is an array of objects:

```
class trust():

    def __init__(self, initialize, sum):

        self.initialize = initialize
        self.trusted_sum = sum
        self.trusted_reference = False

    def reference(self, reference, sum_new):
        self.trusted_reference = reference
        self.trusted_sum = sum_new

# ===================================================================

trusted_sum = 0
trusted_list = []

# create the objects -------------------------
for i in range(3):
    trusted_sum_new = trusted_sum + 0.1
    trusted_list.append(trust(1, trusted_sum_new))

for i in range(3):
    print(trusted_list[i].initialize, trusted_list[i].trusted_sum, 
    trusted_list[i].trusted_reference)

# change values of the objects -------------------------
for i in range(3):
    trusted_sum_new = trusted_list[i].trusted_sum + 0.1
    trusted_list[i].reference(True, trusted_sum_new)

for i in range(3):
    print(trusted_list[i].initialize, trusted_list[i].trusted_sum, 
    trusted_list[i].trusted_reference)
```

Result

```
1 0.1 False
1 0.1 False
1 0.1 False
1 0.2 True
1 0.2 True
1 0.2 True
```