# global variable not updating (Processing.py)

Tags: python, variables, global-variables, processing

I'm using processing.py to make an application for drawing simple lines
this is my code:

```
pointsList =[ ]
points = []


def setup():
    global pointsList, points
    size(400,400)
    stroke(255)
    strokeWeight(5)

def draw():
    global pointsList, points
    background(0)
    for points in pointsList:
        draw_points(points)
    draw_points(points)


def keyPressed():
    global pointsList, points
    if key == 'e':
        try:
            pointsList.append(points)
            points = [] #<--- this right here not updating
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        print(pointsList)

def mouseClicked():
    global points
    print(points)
    points.append((mouseX,mouseY))


def draw_points(points):
    for i in range(len(points)-1):
        draw_line(points[i],points[i+1])

def draw_line(p1,p2):
    line(p1[0],p1[1],p2[0],p2[1])
```

at one point I want to clear my "points" array
but it's not updating

what is causing this?

Comment: how do you know it not udpating ? Did you use `print(points)` to chcek it ? Or maybe it never runs this part of code so it can't update it.

Comment: @furas yes I'v checked with print function
it does update in "keyPressed" function but it's the same in "Draw" or "mouseClicked" function

Comment: did you check if it runs code in `if key == 'e':` ? Maybe `key` is not `e` but `E` ?

Comment: @furas yes i did
and it is "e"

Comment: Try to clear directly after the global statement in keyPressed():. If that does the job then the problem is somewhere below in the function.

Comment: I ran it and it did clear list but after few changes it clears list but code seems identical. Now I try to find out  why it works correctly now.

Comment: @Mace I tried that but problem remains.
same happened to me when i used pyglet library

Comment: Put a print statement with 1 , 2, 3 ...  between all the lines in the function and 'trace' what is happening. Is the code above copied from your source? Could it be that you have a typo in the code you're running?

Comment: Well the answer proves my experience: globals are very tricky in Python. Have you ever tried working with classes? That prevents a lot of troubles. By the way: adding a list to the end of another list usually requires extend() instead of append(). Looking at your code extend seems logical to me.

Comment: @Mace this is the whole application. you think it requires classes?
and i "need" to get list of lists to get something like this https://imgur.com/a/gVz6uVx
I know the difference between append and extend

Comment: The advantage of classes vs global vars is that you would address class vars through 'self.points'. In this case using a local var 'points' inside a function would have had no effect on your application. Your app of course don't require a class. Maybe you could just try it in your next app to experience what is the difference.

Comment: In this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60527871/change-value-of-all-elements-in-a-sum-list-via-class-function/60529845#60529845) I move global vars into a class. It's not that much work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is in different place because you use the same name `points` in function `draw()` in loop `for points` so it assigns last element from `pointList` to `points`

You have to use different name in `draw()` - ie. `items`

```
def draw():
    global pointsList, points

    background(0)

    for items in pointsList:  # <-- use `items`
        draw_points(items)    # <-- use `items`

    draw_points(points)
```

---

```
pointsList = []
points = []

def setup():
    global pointsList, points

    size(400,400)
    stroke(255)
    strokeWeight(5)

def draw():
    global pointsList, points

    background(0)

    for items in pointsList:  # <-- use `items`
        draw_points(items)    # <-- use `items`

    draw_points(points)


def keyPressed():
    global pointsList, points

    if key == 'e':
        try:
            pointsList.append(points)
            points = []
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        print(pointsList)

def mouseClicked():
    global points

    points.append((mouseX,mouseY))
    print(points)

def draw_points(points):
    for i in range(len(points)-1):
        draw_line(points[i], points[i+1])

def draw_line(p1, p2):
    line(p1[0], p1[1], p2[0], p2[1])
```